# Printing strings in a number array

Tags: python, arrays, list, for-loop, list-manipulation

I'm trying to print strings in a matrix. But I couldn't find a solution for that.

```
game_size = 3
matrix = list(range(game_size ** 2))
def board():
    for i in range(game_size):
        for j in range(game_size):
            print('%3d' % matrix[i * game_size + j], end=" ")
        print()
board()
position = int(input("Where to replace ?"))
matrix[position] = "X"
board()
```

First it prints this as exactly what I want

```
  0   1   2 
  3   4   5 
  6   7   8
Where to replace ?5
```

Then It came up with an error;

```
TypeError: %d format: a number is required, not str
```

How can I solve this problem.
I want my output like;

```
  0   1   2 
  3   4   X 
  6   7   8
```

Also X should be stored in array, just printing that doesn't work
Output should be same format as it is.

Comment: use %s instead of %d

Comment: Problem is here: `matrix[position] = "X"`. From now on, the inserted object is a `str` type containing `"X"`. However, in the loop you want to reformat it to `%3d` which is obviously illogical. You cannot reformat the `"X"` string to a number unless it is a number stored as a string.

Comment: Do you think is there a solution for that. I thinked maybe it would solve with if statements. But I couldn't make it.

Comment: Yes, sure @Ahmeed_Hawary already answered you. Use the `%s` (string) format istead of `%d` (number). So you must to be working with a string indentation as `%3s` and not with a number indentation such as `%3d`. Or better is to use the new method: `str.format()`. So there will the following source code: `print('{0:>3}'.format(.....value....),end='')
`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are currently using a format string which requires that all the inputs are integers. I've changed this to using f-strings in the solution below.

```
game_size = 3
matrix = list(range(game_size ** 2))
def board():
    for i in range(game_size):
        for j in range(game_size):
            print(f'{matrix[i * game_size + j]}'.rjust(3), end=" ")
        print()
board()
position = int(input("Where to replace ?"))
matrix[position] = "X"
board()
```

Output with `game_size=3`:

```
0   1   2   
3   4   5   
6   7   8   

Where to replace ?5
0   1   2   
3   4   X   
6   7   8
```

Output with `game_size=5`:

```
  0   1   2   3   4 
  5   6   7   8   9 
 10  11  12  13  14 
 15  16  17  18  19 
 20  21  22  23  24 

Where to replace ?4
  0   1   2   3   X 
  5   6   7   8   9 
 10  11  12  13  14 
 15  16  17  18  19 
 20  21  22  23  24
```

Comment: this doesn't work for me because i want it in that format there should be gaps between numbers

Comment: Actually, this is not dynamic. If i give gamesize 5, last 3 row skids :(

Comment: Yes, it will work, but if you run the code on an older Python version where the `print(f"{foobar}")` formatting style did not exist, the code will not work there. Use standard formatting rather...as I mentioned above in my comments. So use `print("{}".format(foobar))` instead of the new style format.

Comment: BTW this method `.rjust()` is not a neccessary ! You can use the following syntax instead: `print(f'{matrix[ i * game_size + j ]:>3}', end='')`